# Remove a syntax from Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublimetext3

Every gulpfile I have opens with the syntax Gulpfile JS. I have tried changing that by using the "Open all with current extension" as Javascript but it does not stick. Any idea how to get rid of this syntax? It appears to be part of the SetiUI package.

Comment: No, `Gulpfile JS` is not part of the standard distribution.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Press <kbd>Ctrl + Backtick</kbd> to open the console, paste the following code, and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>.

```
sublime.active_window().new_file().run_command( "append", { "characters": "\n".join( sorted( sublime.find_resources( "*.sublime-syntax" ) + sublime.find_resources( "*.tmLanguage" ) ) ) } )
```

---

A list of all installed `sublime-syntax` & `tmLanguage` files will open in a new tab.  You can then search for the syntax file you want to remove.

---

I recommend using [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to open the syntax file and comment out the contents, rather than deleting the file.

This will effectively disable the syntax, maintain the original copy of the syntax within the package, and prevent a plugin update from replacing the deleted syntax file.

---

[image: Demo]

Comment: That brings up a list which includes a SetiUI gulpfile which I had deleted in my earlier attempt. I can confirm that no file exist yet it still comes up in this list?  ST is caching something. Even with the file gone it does not fix issue though.

Comment: @Yashua: Did you delete it from `Packages/SetiUI` or `SetiUI.sublime-package`? I'm guessing that the file might exist within the `sublime-package`, in which case you can use [**PackageResourceViewer**](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/PackageResourceViewer) to edit the file with the `PackageResourceViewer: Open Resource` command. Once you have navigated to the file in question, comment the contents out & save it.  This will create a `Packages/SetiUI` instance of the file which overrides the `sublime-package` instance, and will prevent SetiUI from replacing the deleted file when it updates.

Comment: Thank you that did the trick. I could not comment it out as I expected content but I changed the name of the files it tries to match. Not being recognized as a JS file all my js completion plugins failed to work.